# Why is $A \propto 1/r^3, B \propto 1/r^4$, far away from circular loops

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current, magnetostatics, multipole-expansion

Two equal circular current loops are placed coaxially with each other. The loops have equal but opposite currents $I$.

$$ A \propto r^{-l} $$
$$ B \propto r^{-k} $$

, where $A$ is the vector potential, and $B$ is the magnetic field. What is $l$ and $k$, when you are at a distance far away?

I thought that I could approximate this system as a dipole system, which should imply that $A \propto r^{-2}, B \propto r^{-3}$, however the correct answer is $l=3, k=4$, and I can't seem to understand why.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single current loop is already a [magnetic dipole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole),
thus having a far field
$$A \propto r^{-2},$$
$$B \propto r^{-3}.$$
(See especially the section [Magnetic dipole - External magnetic field produced by a magnetic dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#External_magnetic_field_produced_by_a_magnetic_dipole_moment).)

Hence, when combining two opposite current loops
(i.e. two opposite magnetic dipoles)
separated by a small distance,
you get a magnetic quadrupole.
The far fields of the two dipoles nearly cancel,
and you get one more power of $r^{-1}$ in the resulting quadrupole field:
$$A \propto r^{-3},$$
$$B \propto r^{-4}.$$